# How to reverse value of string array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's say I have this array :

```
fruits: string[] = ['banana', 'strawberry', 'kiwi', 'apple'];
```

How can I do to have :

```
fruits = ['ananab', 'yrrebwarts', 'iwki', 'elppa'];
```

Comment: You were not able to find how to reverse a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'strawberry', 'kiwi', 'apple'].map(item => item.split('').reverse().join(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

First we need to travel the array (we will use a map)

```
fruits.map(ele => { 
})
```

Then we need to reverse the order of the string there (we do this by converting the string back to array using split(''), then we reverse the array using reverse(), and finally we use join() to put it together as a string

```
fruits.map(ele => {
  return ele.split('').reverse().join('')
})
```

Finally we save this into the reversedFruits and voila

```
const reversedFruist = fruits.map(ele => {
    return ele.split('').reverse().join('')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 fruits = fruits.map(i => i = i.split("").reverse().join(""));
```